# Journey Builder Automation Audience - Journey entry activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio

Can I have multiple Journeys reference the same automation for entry into those journeys?

I know that's not BEST practice, but we have an onboarding campaign that utilizes "accelerators" if the client is taking the right action and evaluating the next steps independently based on recent action with a fallback of no-action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not best practice as you say, but I know you can setup multiple journeys with the same automation if you are using a data extension entry event.

When you select the same automation as the entry source in Journey Builder it will automatically add both Journey entry events to Automation Studio.

[image]

Comment: But you cannot define that entry event in the automation.  It's system generated.  How have you done this?

Comment: For Data Extension Journey entry events you never define them in automation studio. You select the automation as the entry source in Journey Builder and upon activating it creates the "Journey Entry: Audience" activity in Automation Studio for you.

Comment: Right, but it’s my impression that it’s a 1 to 1 relationship based on my last attempt to pair 5 journeys to 1 automation.

Comment: I've never tried to do 5 journeys so maybe that is too many but I added a screenshot to my answer with 2 journey entries on the same automation. I ran that automation and had the same audience go into both journeys. Is that not what you are looking to do?

Comment: That’s exactly what I’m trying to do’. I’ll test again in the morning

Comment: Did you have to Activate journey THEN set up the automation schedule for it to capture the journey Entry activity?

Comment: I setup the automation with a filter or in this case sql activity first. I then create a journey and select data extension as the entry event. I select the automation as the entry schedule and activate the journey. Journey entry activity should appear in the automation. You can then make another journey and select the same data extension and automation as schedule. Activate that journey and then you should have 2 journey entry events associated with the same automation like in the screenshot above.

Comment: Built a test DE, automation and journeys for this and got it to work.  BUT it's not working for my specific use case.  All in all, your answer is correct.  I do have an open support ticket for why it's not working for my use case.